# Al serializar dos arrayList, no se porduce la persistencia que me gustaría

Tags: java

Es mi primera pregunta lo haré lo mejor posible.

Tengo 2 clases. `class Perro` con dos campos String uno nombre y otro raza. Otra `class Persona` con otros dos campos, uno String nombre y otro Perro perro. 
Creo dos `ArrayList<Perro>` y otro `ArrayList<Persona>`.

Primero creo un objeto tipo Perro, y después otro de tipo Persona al que le paso el objeto Perro creado. De modo que cuando estan recién creados todo cambio que realice en el objeto perro, a pedir las caracteristicas de objeto persona se ve reflejado todos los cambios realizados en el objeto perro. Hasta ahí todo perfecto.

Cuando serializa los objetos creados en ambos `ArrayList`, y los cargo, parece como si el objeto Perro que tiene el Objeto Persona, se crease una copia exacta pero ya no es el objeto perro creado al principio. De tal modo que si modifico el objeto Perro que esta en el `ArrayList<Perro>`, ya no se ve reflejado al pedir las caracteristicas de la `Persona`.

```
public void guardarObjeto(){
    try{
        ObjectOutputStream salida =new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream("fichero/listaPersonas.txt"));
        salida.writeObject(listaPersonas);
        salida.close();            
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

public void recuperarObjeto(){
    try{
        ObjectInputStream entrada =new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream ("fichero/listaPersonas.txt"));
        listaPersonas= (ArrayList<Persona>) entrada.readObject();
        entrada.close();           
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Esos son los métodos que he utilizado para guardar y cargar ambas lista, cambiado lógicamente el tipo que almacena el `Arraylist`.

Comment: Si pones todo el código podremos reproducir tus resultados. ¿Cuál es la pregunta? ¿Qué esperabas y no esta sucediendo?

Comment: Bueno, creo que no has entendido del todo como funciona la POO y lo de los objetos. Funciona como en la vida real, es decir, que un perro es un perro y una persona es una persona... entonces esas dos clases deberían ser independientes. Un ejemplo de clase dependiente de otra sería: una clase `Persona` y una clase `Deportista` ya que ambas podrían compartir métodos. Otras dos clases relacionadas podrían ser una clase `Animal`y una clase `Perro`. La idea es poder reutilizar los métodos de una clase en otra. En la clase `Animal` no tendrías el método `ladrar`porque no todos los animales ladran.

Comment: hay alguna forma de adjuntar un fichero .rar con todas las clase?

Answer (score 0):

Justo como lo mencionas en el texto de tu pregunta, al recuperar los objetos se crean nuevas instancias a partir de los datos *serializados*.  Por lo tanto si modificas la instancia original, dichos cambios no se ven reflejados en la instancia creada a partir de los datos recuperados.

Normalmente la *serialización* se utiliza para permitir transferir el estado de los objetos entre contextos de ejecución, ya sea a través del tiempo (guardar el estado de los objetos entre sesiones) o para cruzar las fronteras entre capas de ejecución (transferir el estado de objetos del servidor al cliente o viceversa).  Por lo que en el caso general, el objeto original desaparece del contexto de ejecución después de que ocurre la serialización.

En todo caso lo que buscas es reutilizar las instancias existentes en tu contexto de ejecución y actualizar su estado a partir de datos serializados.  Entonces, necesitas crear código más complejo que la implementación simple que presentas.